# Is there a simple way to upload a Tab delimited file to SQL Server without using BCP?

Tags: sql, sql-server

After using BCP for a year and fooling around with character encoding (x-UTF-16LE-BOM? Really?) we want a better solution. I have worked with Oracle and it is as simple as selecting a table and uploading the file.

Is there anything that can do that with SQL Server?

- BCP must use x-UTF-16LE-BOM or it chokes.
- BULK INSERT requires the file to be on the SQL Server instance (really?)

I have Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio but it doesn't seem able to do it.

Any help? We are in the Azure Cloud and I want it simple!

Comment: You can import a file using SSMS - right-click on DB>tasks>import data

Comment: I've been similarly annoyed with the available tools, *especially* the Import Wizard in SSMS, so I wrote some code to do it in a way that was easy for me.  If you're OK with a system scripting tool instead of a GUI, and OK with Python, you can get the code here: https://pypi.python.org/pypi/execsql -- documentation is here: http://pythonhosted.org/execsql/

Comment: AFAIK `BULK INSERT` can insert from a UNC. There's just a bunch of stuff you need to configure. https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/44524/bulk-insert-through-network When you say Azure cloud, can you be more specific? Is your SQL running inside a VM or is it a Azure SQL Database? Where are your source files? I currently use BULK INSER to load files from blob Storage

Comment: and if you're saying Oracle is simpler than SQL then I just have to leave this here https://www.oreilly.co.jp/BOOK/unixback/download/oracle.html